# If Elif statements in python

Tags: python, jython, if-statement

I wrote a program incorrectly.

```
def changeByThirds(pic):
  w= getWidth (pic)
  h = getHeight(pic)

  newPic = makeEmptyPicture(w,h)
  for x in range (0,w):
    for y in range (0,h):
      pxl = getPixel(pic, x, y)

      if (y<h/3):
#some code

      if (y>(h*2/3)):
#some code

      else:
#some code

  return (newPic)
```

When I execute this program, the first if statement `if (y<h/3):` is ignored, so it runs as if the first if was not there at all.

```
if (y>(h*2/3)):
#some code

      else:
#some code
```

I discovered the correct way to write the code was like this:

```
def changeByThirds(pic):
  w= getWidth (pic)
  h = getHeight(pic)

  newPic = makeEmptyPicture(w,h)
  for x in range (0,w):
    for y in range (0,h):
      pxl = getPixel(pic, x, y)

      if (y<h/3):
#some code

      elif (y>(h*2/3)):
#some code

      else:
#some code

  return (newPic)
```

However, my question is;

In the first code- Why does it bypass the first if statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first example both `if` conditions are going to be checked even if the first `if` was `False`.

So the first one actually look like this:

---

```
  if (y<h/3):
     #some code
```

---

```
  if (y>(h*2/3)):
      #some code
  else:
      #some code
```

---

**Example:**

```
>>> x = 2

if x == 2:
     x += 1      
if x == 3:       #due to the modification done by previous if, this condition
                 #also becomes True, and you modify x again 
     x += 1
else:    
     x+=100
>>> x            
4
```

But in an `if-elif-else` block if any of the them is `True` then the code breaks out and the next conditions are not checked.

---

```
  if (y<h/3):
      #some code
  elif (y>(h*2/3)):
      #some code
  else:
     #some code
```

---

Example:

```
>>> x = 2
if x == 2:
    x += 1
elif x == 3:    
    x += 1
else:    
    x+=100
...     
>>> x             # only the first-if changed the value of x, rest of them
                  # were not checked
3
```

Answer (score 5):

In the first program the `second if` was overwriting what was done in the `first if`, it was not "bypassed". That's why it worked in the second program when you changed to `elif`.